# asdict() inside .format() in a Python class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

How can I use `asdict()` method inside `.format()` in oder to unpack the class attributes.
So that instead of this:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, asdict

@dataclass
class InfoMessage():
    training_type: str
    duration: float
    distance: float
    message = 'Training type: {}; Duration: {:.3f} ч.; Distance: {:.3f}'

    def get_message(self) -> str:
        return self.message.format(self.training_type, self.duration, self.distance)
```

I could write something like this:

```
@dataclass
class InfoMessage():
    training_type: str
    duration: float
    distance: float
    message = 'Training type: {}; Duration: {:.3f} ч.; Distance: {:.3f}'

    def get_message(self) -> str:
        return self.message.format(asdict().keys())
```

Comment: Maybe you want `*self.asdict().values()` ?

Comment: I used .format(*self.asdict(InfoMessage()).values())
It says AttributeError: 'InfoMessage' object has no attribute 'asdict'

Comment: asdict isn't used like that... you need asdict(self)

Comment: .format(*asdict(self).values()) worked! Thank you!

Comment: Issue has been resolved. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`asdict` should be called on an instance of a class - `self`, in this case. Additionally, you don't need the dict's keys, you need its values, which you can spread using the `*` operator:

```
def get_message(self) -> str:
    return self.message.format(*asdict(self).values())
    # Here --------------------^
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `**asdict`.

```
@dataclass
class InfoMessage():
    training_type: str
    duration: float
    distance: float
    message = '{Training type}; {Duration:.3f} ч.; {Distance::.3f}'

    def get_message(self) -> str:
        return self.message.format(**asdict(self))
```